# QTableCellWidget is not hiding

Tags: qt, qtablewidget

I have placed a widget in `QTableWidget` using `setCellWidget` method.

But when I am calling `cellWidget(row,col)->hide()` or `cellWidget(row,col)->setEnable(false)` widget is not hiding.

Can anyone suggest a solution? I am using Qt 5.5.0

Comment: I think it is Qt bug, it is reported here: https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-22490

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may be able to by-pass the mentioned bug by overwriting the paintEvent in a derived QTableWidget class and hide the widgets after the QTableWidget finished painting.

```
DerivedQTableWidget::paintEvent(QPaintEvent * e)
{
   QTableWidget::paintEvent(e);

   // do the hiding here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

So sorry for my late answer but it may be useful for others:
the simplest working solution is to change the parent of the widget. you can make a fake object and set it as the parent.

```
QWidget* fake= new QWidget;
QWidget* cell = ui->tableWidget->cellWidget(row, col);
cell ->setParent(fake);
```